# Instance variable access by using Inheritance concept

Tags: java, inheritance

I am using a Inheritance concept here. I have extended class A(Superclass) into class B(Subclass). And I have created an object of a subclass and by using that object I have called add() method. But it is printing a value 5(Super Class).
Why it didn't take subclass's value which is 10 ?

```
class A{
    int a=5;

    public void add(){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
class B extends A{
    int a=10;


}
public class InheritExample {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        B b1=new B();
        b1.add();
    }
}
```

Help Appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no overriding of instance variables. Overriding only works on instance methods. Therefore, the method `add` of class `A` has access only to the `a` variable declared in `A`, even if you call that method for an instance of class `B`.

Comment: but if we do `System.out.println(new B().a);` it prints `10` and if we print `System.out.println(this.a);` it prints `5` but `this` is `B's` object check https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8e16a17ae260e36a1bee . If both the cases have same `B's` object then why outputs different?

Comment: @codegasmer `B` has two instance variables called `a`. One if declared in `B` class and hides the one declared in `A` class. A method of class `A` doesn't know about `a` of class `B`. On the other hand, a method of class `B` only sees `a` of class `B`.

Comment: When you say new B().a you're not using a super class as a reference holder. That is., calling new B().a is not the same as A o = new B(); o.a; this refers to the instance where it is used, so where you use this matters